# How to use hasOptionsMenu() in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment-oncreateview

My code shows an error with the text:
"Fragment.hasOptionsMenu can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.fragment with prefix androidx from groupId=Personal Pocket Dictionary"

I've imported the library and have the right dependency
"implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version""
so none of that is the issue.

Not sure how to fix this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` instead.

Comment: This is the one

Comment: Consider marking my answer as accepted or, in case the issue wasn't solved, please inform about it.

Comment: gotcha this was my first question, i was wondering how to do that and literally had to google it. not too apparent when youre new

Comment: Haha, no problem